# Any way to identify a mobile phone web user other than using a cookie?

Tags: android, iphone, windows-phone-7, blackberry, mobile

I have a web page which will use a rating system entered by web user. There's no login functionality. Web page is mainly accessed by mobile phone users. On a desktop computer I can use the browser's ip address and cookie to determine if user visited the web page earlier. I will use the ip address also for users who erase their cookie. If the ip address is in database, the user is not new. (ignoring shared ip addresses like AOL)

For a web user on a mobile phone or device, is a cookie the only way to identify a prior user?
Is it true mobile phones do not have ip addresses sent by the phone's browser?

Answer (score 3):

> Is it true mobile phones do not have ip addresses sent by the phone's browser?

Everything accessing your webpage has an ip, mobile phone or not. However, the IP of the phone may change (if the phone loses signal for instance), or many phones may share the same IP. Therefore, cookies are your best bet to identify an user.

Note that it's the same for desktop browsers. I'm living with my girlfriend, and we're sharing the same internet connection. Therefore, we always have the same IP. If you don't use cookies, you won't be able to tell us apart.

Comment: +1 million. IP address _never_ == user, most entire companies have a single external IP address.

Comment: Agreed. Even for single user homes, many users (myself included) get a dynamic IP via DHCP from their ISP, so there is no guarantee that an IP will ever stay consistent for very long unless the user pays extra for a static IP.  Never use an IP to identify a user. Always require some kind of identifier instead.  If you don't want users to login to your website, then at least allow them to type in their name for later reuse.

Answer (score 1):

Mobile phones also have IP adresses, but usually they come from providers walled garden, and subject to NAT - not usefull to identify.  Crapware (logos/ringtones) seller redirect mobile customers to WAP interfaces, go get to phone ID and extort user money over carrier billing.

So, cookie is your best bet

Answer (score 1):

As other answers, IP is always sent but does not reflect 1 IP = 1 User.

Since you are dealing with Mobile, you could use one of those:

- Cookies: Simple but volatile, since some old browsers delete them when closing but still the most supported;
- HTML5: If you think in dealing with high profile devices, probably they will have HTML5 support and then you can use their storage. localStorage, SQLlite, etc. For this, i suggest using jQuery's jStorage plugin, since will pick the best of each. This one is volatile as cookie, because clearing browser data/cache delete it as well;
- MSISDN: This one is not so used anymore since companies are not sharing freely but you can try in your country. Inside the headers that the mobile browser send, one of them is `msisdn` (other names can be `x-msisdn`, `x-nokia-msisdn`, etc) and they are literally the user's phone number. It's always the full number, with country code, region code and number.

If it does not come, simply the company does not share it without agreement and your server IP's in their firewall's whitelist.

If comes but all scrambled, the company share but encoded. Same as above.

If comes, then you have the info that this is a single device (phone numbers does not repeat, like IP) and can use this to know if that that device visited or not.